# dash_bio.jsme in callbacks

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm attempting to develop a Dash app featuring a `dash_bio.jsme` object that enables users to sketch a molecule. Following this, a callback function will scour a database for the corresponding structure (using the SMILES notation of the molecule).
Therefore, I need to export the SMILES from the jsme through a `@callback` and save it in a separate variable.

I've found a JS function that precisely fits my requirements (`jsme.smiles()`). However, I'm unsure whether or not it's possible to use it in my Python script and if yes how.
I've attempted to export the function through my callback by employing component IDs '`children`' or '`smile`' in the following manner:

```
@callback(
    Output('smiles-output', 'children'),
    Input('smiles-input', 'value')
)
def update_smiles_output(smiles):
    return smiles
```

Although I receive no errors, the smiles-output appears as `None`.

Are there any other component IDs that might work, or does anyone have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to execute javascript from inside a callback you can use a client side callback  https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks